# Listing all products that contain current tag (on product page)

Tags: shopify, liquid

I've tried searching but couldn't figure this out.

I'm wondering if it's possible to list all products that use the same tag as the current product.

For instance, if I'm on a product page that uses the tag "red", I'd like to list all of the other products that also use that tag.

Is this possible and if so how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways but I'm not sure if these will do you any good.

1) AJAX

The easiest ways is to make an AJAX request to the `/collections/all/TAG` and get the required products and append them.

2) Paginate hack

```
{% paginate collection.all.products by 1000 %}
  {%- for _product in collection.all.products -%}
    {%- if _product.tags contains 'red' -%}
      list the product
    {%- endif -%}
  {%- endfor -%}
{% endpaginate %}
```

Please note that this may increase the load time drastically depending how many products you have.